# UICollectionView allow user to choose cell colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am making an app for tracking points, basically the user can add a new cell to the `UICollectionView` with their name and a default of 0 points.

I don't have an issue as such I am just not sure on how to accomplish a task.
When the user creates a new cell I want them to be able to choose the color of their cell from 4 predefined options.

If anyone could explain to me how I could accomplish this it would make my week.

(I tried to add images to show my views to give a better understanding but I don't have enough rep)

EDIT : Perhaps I should of mentioned that this is my first iOS project at work and im a super noob, if anyone could explain to me the steps neccessary to gets this to work that would be great.

This method gets called when the user creates the new cell. (This is contained in a class with all my SQL methods together)

```
+(void) writeData:(NSString*)name {

[self databaseInit];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &peopleDB ) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO PEOPLE (NAME, POINTS) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%i\")",name, 0];


    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2( peopleDB, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Added Successfully");

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%s SQLITE_ERROR '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(peopleDB), sqlite3_errcode(peopleDB));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(peopleDB);
}
```

}

Then in my ViewController.m (main view)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"customBrownieCell" bundle:nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cbCell"];
people2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[databaseClass createDB];
people2 = [databaseClass getData];
```

}

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cbCell";
customCell *cell = (customCell *)[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier
                                                                                    forIndexPath:indexPath];
PersonObject *a = (PersonObject*)[people2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.nameLabel.text = a.name;
cell.pointsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", a.points];
cell.idLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", a.ID];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I seriously dislike ppl who downvote without stating WHY they do it. It should be more transparent who is behind the downvotes. I'll upvote it just to return it to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a flag on whatever object (if any) is behind the cell, and in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you would set the background color based on this flag.

How to give the user this choice will depend on how the "add cell" functionality is implemented. If you show us your code, I could probably be more specific or maybe give you an example.

Comment: Thanks I used what you said here plus a lot of research and got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

In

```
- ( UICollectionViewCell* ) collectionView:( UICollectionView* ) collectionView 
cellForItemAtIndexPath:( NSIndexPath* ) indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [ collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier 
forIndexPath:indexPath ];
// ....
```

just add

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = your_color;
```

Comment: This much I understand, my issue is not knowing how to get the users choice.